# Proof about irreducibility of a $K[G]$-Module

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I don't know where to start and I'm looking for help on the following problem.

> Let V be a finite dimensional $K[G]$-Module ($G$ finite) and $\mathrm{char}(K)=0$ or coprime to $\mathrm{Ord}(G)$.
>   Prove that if every $K[G]$-homomorphism $V \to V$ is a scalar multiple of $\mathrm{id}_{V}$ then $V$ is irreducible.

We obviously can apply Maschke's Lemma but how can we use this direct sum decomposition to deduce the irreduciblity.

Comment: If $V = W \oplus W'$ is a direct sum of $k[G]$-submodules, consider the projection followed by the inclusion $V \to W \subset V$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned, we know from Maschke's theorem that if $W \subset V$ is a $k[G]$-submodule, then there is a decomposition of $V$ as direct sum of $k[G]$-submodules $V = W \oplus W'$.

Consider the projection followed by the inclusion $V \to W \subset V$. This gives a $k[G]$-endomorphism of $V$. What can you say about it?

Comment: For your information, Schur's lemma states a kind of converse: if $k$ is **algebraically closed** and $V$ is an irreducible $k[G]$-module, then $End_{k[G]}(V) \simeq k \cdot \mathrm{id}_V$.

Comment: the only thing which comes to my mind is that W' must be trivial in the projection you suggested since by assumption we have only multiples of the identity

Comment: @johnka : this is almost correct, well done! In fact, we get $W' = 0$ if the above map is a _non-zero_ multiple of the identity. In the case where the above map is _zero_ instead, we simply get $W=0$.

Comment: alright thanks alot i think i got it, if any questions still arise i hopefully can feel free to post a further comment

Comment: @johnka : I'm glad to hear that my hints were useful. You're welcome! I will try to address any further question :-)